# Searching movie_title near episode number in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

When I search "it episode 2"
I want to see results as follow:
'**It episode 2**',
'**It episode 1**',
... (other movies contain "it" in them)

But I d **NOT** want to see episode 2 of other movies (without "it" in their title like Annabelle episode 2) in my results.
How could I do that?

Here is my mapping

I have a field as "title_fa" where I have removed my stop words like 'episode' or '2'

I have a field as "title_fa.title_fa" where I have only keep my stop words like 'episode' or '2'

```
"title_fa": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "basic_title_fa",
                "boost": 40,
                "norms": "false",
                "fields": {
                    "title_fa": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "basic_title_fa_child",
                        "boost": 30,
                        "norms": "false",
                    },
                    "title_fa_raw": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "title_fa_keyword",
                        "boost": 80,
                        "norms": "false",
                    },
                    "with_ngram": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "ngram_fa",
                        "boost": 2
                    },
                    "with_back_ngram": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "ngram_back_fa",
                        "boost": 2
                    }
                }
            },
```

Here is my query search:

```
query = {
        "from": 0,
        "size": 300,
        "query": {
            "function_score": {
                "query": {
                    "multi_match": {
                            "query": keyword,
                            "type": "most_fields",
                            "fields": ["title_fa", "title_fa.title_fa"]
                        }
                },
                "functions": [
                    {
                        "weight": 2,
                        "filter": {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": keyword,
                                "fields": [
                                    "title_fa"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "weight": 1,
                        "filter": {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": keyword,
                                "fields": [
                                    "title_fa.title_fa"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Some how I want to sum score of title_fa.title_fa only if title_fa it self have score

Comment: you need to be more restrictive with the matching, so as to require all (remaining) tokens are required to match in `title_fa`. You will need to adjust the `minimum_should_match` parameter to achieve that.  I don't think you can do it in a single `multi_match` either but you could split the fields into separate clauses in a bool's `must` and `should` block and that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a solution.
Using [Query Rescore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/filter-search-results.html#query-rescorer).

Here I will use "title_fa" for my search (title without common words like 'episode' in it)
Then I will rescore results based on the other field ("title_fa.title_fa" that have common words like 'episode' in it).

Here is My search query:

```
        "from": 0,
        "size": 300,
        "query": {
            "dis_max": {
                "queries": [
                    {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": keyword,
                            "type": "most_fields",
                            "fields": ["title_fa", "title_fa.title_fa_raw"]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "rescore": {
            "window_size": 50,
            "query": {
                "rescore_query": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": keyword,
                        "fields": [
                            "title_fa.title_fa",
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "query_weight": 0.7,
                "rescore_query_weight": 1.2
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about built in Span query and having a boolean clause which ranks span query higher